# Coninutity of this function in interval $(0,1)$

Tags: functions, continuity

> Let $f(x)$ be the function defined on the interval $(0,1)$ by
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
>          x(1-x)  \quad\text{if}\quad x \in \Bbb Q \\
>          \frac{1}{4}-x(1-x) \quad\text{if}\quad x \in \Bbb R - \Bbb Q 
>        \end{cases}
> $$
>   Then $f$ is continuous at how many points in $(0,1)$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, What are your own thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

The following is an observation which can be proved easily using the sequential definition of continuity for a function at a point.
Consider any open interval $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.
Let $f,g:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions.  Let $h:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $h(x)=f(x),\mbox{ if }x\in I\cap\mathbb{Q},\mbox{ and }h(x)=g(x),\mbox{ if }x\in I\cap(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})$.
Then $h$ is continuous at $x\in I$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$.